# Apache Camel Route: "Cannot assign requested address" when trying to fetch data from server

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, jetty

I want to fetch data from a very simple webserver which shows me a page when being called in the browser providing me with a couple of data. The page automatically updated itself very some seconds and shows:

```
analog input 0 is 1023
analog input 1 is 109
analog input 2 is 0
analog input 3 is 415
analog input 4 is 0
analog input 5 is 40
```

In the final program, I want to fetch the data from the page and convert it to an influx time series via apache camel. I learned up to now that the jetty component is the way to go and configured my route as follows:

```
public class HttpReaderRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Autowired
    private FrameworkConfig frameworkConfig;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        String sourceString = "jetty:http://server.i.want.to.poll:8080/?sessionSupport=true";
        String targetString = "stream:out";
        // String targetString = "influxdb://influxDb?databaseName=" //
        // + frameworkConfig.getInfluxDb().getDatabaseName() //
        // + "&retentionPolicy=" //
        // + frameworkConfig.getInfluxDb().getRetentionPolicy();

        System.out.println(sourceString);

        from(sourceString)
                .log("Received data server") //
                .to(targetString);
    }
}
```

However, I get either a `org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address` or - if I skip use the format `jetty:http:server.i.want.to.poll:8080`, I get a "permission denied".

The related configuration class looks as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class HttpClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingConnectionManager() {
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingConnectionManager = new 

PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
            poolingConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(10);
            return poolingConnectionManager;
    }
}
```

Maybe it is worth to mention that I am using spring.boot.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to poll data from some existing web service with Apache Camel? If yes, you should use the [HTTP4 Component](https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/http4-component.html) instead of [Jetty componet](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/jetty-component.html).

That's the quick answer to get you to next step, as fast as possible.
You could do something like

```
from("timer:hello?period=2000").routeId("test_route")
.to("http4://example.com/")
.log("${body}")
.to("file:target/messages");
```

after adding dependency

```xml
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-http4</artifactId>
  <version>X.X.X</version>
 </dependency>
```

We need to dig a bit further here, since chances of people stumbling at the same issue is high, because [CAMEL-13220](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-13220) has removed `Producer` support on the jetty component in June 2019. It means Jetty 
can't do HTTP Client function anymore.

- The route in the code sample starts as `from("jetty:http://server.i.want.to.poll:8080/?sessionSupport=true")`. That code actually sets up an HTTP Server (or a Consumer in Camel terminology, as shown [here in old docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.2/html/apache_camel_component_reference/idu-jetty) ). Very likely, in OP's test infrastructure:
- `server.i.want.to.poll` is `localhost`
- There is some other service listening on 8080, possibly the service OP is trying to connect to. That could be what's causing the `java.net.BindException`
- In the past Jetty component could be used as a producer and as a consumer. If the OP is using 2.x versions of Camel, it is still be possible to use Jetty component as an HTTP Client (a Producer), with a route like `from("direct:start").to("jetty://http://www.google.com")`. However, I'd recommend to stick to HTTP/HTTP4 components as applicable.

PS: My test setup is a Spring boot application, running `Camel 3.0.0-M4`

Comment: Graag gedaan! 

Comment: @ShellGragon how can we receive data from a server via SNMP traps? can you give me an example? like in above case you suggested using http4 with an exaple.